# Git merge two local branches

Tags: git, merge

I have branch `Master`, `branchA` and `branchB`.
Now I'm working in the `branchA` and I need to merge `branchA` with `branchB` and proceed my work in the `branchA`. All files are comitted in the `branchA` and `branchB`.

What's the fast way to implement it?

Answer (score 526, accepted):

If I understood your question, you want to merge `branchB` into `branchA`. To do so,

first checkout `branchA` like below,

```
git checkout branchA
```

Then execute the below command to merge `branchB` into `branchA`:

```
git merge branchB
```

You can also condense this into one liner:

```
git merge branchA branchB
```

Comment: We need to make sure that branches A and B exist on local repository. Only then we can perform merge.

Comment: The question is explicit: `I have branch Master, branch A and branch B.`

Comment: I do this and got `Branch B|MERGING`. What does this mean? I want to have a final result of  `Branch B` only.

Comment: @NemraKhalil I can't tell what you're trying to do, it could be normal, could be something where Branch B doesn't matter (you start with branches a and b and you want to only be left with branch b, if that's what you mean then just delete branch a, tho I doubt this is what you want since you'd probably be on a very different question), merging is where two branches are combined into a single branch, so you might have added tabs on one branch and full screen support on another, you could merge them to have both on a single branch (as a massive oversimplification)

Comment: @Abimaran Kugathasan What is the command to merge say only 1 file from branch B into branch A ?

Eg: There are 10 files in branch B modified but I want to merge only 1 file from branch B to branch A

Answer (score 176):

**Here's a clear picture:**

Assuming we have branch-A and branch-B

We want to merge branch-B into branch-A

```
on branch-B -> A: switch to branch-A

on branch-A: git merge branch-B
```

Comment: this isn't clearer at all, just post the terminal input it's much easier to understand

Comment: This isn't clear enough answer .... what does it mean "update the branch-B" ... there are many ways of doing that, which one? ... instead of switch git checkout branch-A is more understandable

Answer (score 9):

The answer from the Abiraman was absolutely correct. However, for newbies to git, they might forget to pull the repository. Whenever you want to do a merge from branchB into branchA.
First checkout and take pull from branchB (Make sure that, your branch is updated with remote branch)

```
git checkout branchB
```

```
git pull
```

Now you local branchB is updated with remote branchB
Now you can checkout to branchA

```
git checkout branchA
```

Now you are in branchA, then you can merge with branchB using following command

```
git merge branchB
```

Comment: Why would you pull during this process?  The question says **local**.

Answer (score 2):

on branchB do `$git checkout branchA` to switch to branch A

on branchA do `$git merge branchB`

That's all you need.

Answer (score 0):

For merging first branch to second one:

on first branch: git merge secondBranch

on second branch: Move to first branch-> git checkout firstBranch-> git merge secondBranch

Answer (score -1):

If you or another dev will not work on branchB further, I think it's better to keep commits in order to make reverts without headaches. So ;

```
git checkout branchA
git pull --rebase branchB
```

It's important that branchB shouldn't be used anymore.

For more ; https://www.derekgourlay.com/blog/git-when-to-merge-vs-when-to-rebase/

Comment: In its title, the question relates to local repositories — for which `pull` will not work.

Comment: You are right, I just thought adding this knowledge would be a plus because probably local branch will be pushed at the end. But I missed the point you indicated, I would better add this as a comment not as an answer. Thanks for warning me.

Answer (score -1):

It is very simple,
you need to first checkout to branchA, for this you can use command `git checkout branchA`.
Now you are in branchA, just hit the merge command `git merge branchB`.
And you are done!!!

Comment: ye, but about same was written here already says 2014 and yours 2011.

Answer (score -3):

I would recommend below one if anyone looking to fetch remote changes as well:

```
git pull
git merge origin/development
```