# git merge two branches (both different from master)

Tags: git

Say you have a repository with four branches : *master,br2,br3,br4*. Also say that in your local directory you've cloned only *br2*, not the *master*. So,

```
$git branch
* br2
```

Now, I want to merge in *br2* the branch *br3*.
Here, *git clone --single branch* won't work, right?
Since I except to have, before merge

```
$git branch
* br2
  br3
```

I tried the following

```
$git checkout -b br3 [last commit hash of br3]
fatal: reference is not a tree: 9565138...
```

How can I do this, i.e. to get br3 in my local repo.

EDIT 1.

```
$git branch --list --all
*br2
remotes/origin/br2
```

Also,

```
$git checkout --track origin/br3
fatal: 'origin/br3' is not a commit and a branch 'br3' cannot be created from it
```

Comment: `git checkout -b br3` means you are creating a new branch br3 however you already have it..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git merge two local branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25053697/git-merge-two-local-branches)

Comment: What does `git branch --list --all` say? You might already have `origin/br3` but you might not be aware of it; if you do, the problem is solved. If you don't have it, you can `fetch` it and the problem is solved too.

Comment: Exactly @flaxel `git checkout br3` (without `-b`)  then  `git merge br2` , I wish this helped you fix the issue @111

Comment: It's Easy. 1) Go to br2 merge master, Resolved conflict if occur. 2) Go to br3 merge br2, Resolved conflict if occur :)

Comment: Thanks @matt, the following worked : git fetch origin br3:temp, now I have the branch temp and I can merge or whatever.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I didn't get it quite right off the top of my head, but this is a standard problem so the duplicate is sufficient.